# "mosquito net" vs "mosquito netting"

Tags: word-usage

http://www.google.com/m?hl=en-US&ie=UTF-8&source=android-browser&q=mosquito+netting

> According to the above-mentioned links,are there any differences between "mosquito net" and "mosquito netting"?

Comment: Compare "I bought 100 square meters of mosquito netting" and "I bought 10 mosquito nets" - it's hard to switch the words "netting" and "net" in these sentences; each word feels more natural in its own sentence.

Comment: @CowperKettle's implicit analogy of netting:net to cloth:clothes sounds convincing. The [*netting*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/netting) is the material, and the [*net*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mosquito_net) is the finished product.

Answer (score 1):

Netting does not mean a finished product though in context, it could. **"We used mosquito netting to help prevent insect bites."**

**We used mosquito nets to help prevent insect bites.** This  means we used an already made (perhaps bed-shaped) net.

**I bought mosquito netting and made a canopy  for my daughter's bed.** This means I used an unfinished material and fashioned something from it. Mosquito net could be used in that sentence, but it could cause confusion because it lacks clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any significant difference between those two terms. In English, you can sometimes refer to a single concept using two, three or even four different words. For example, you can say [a car accident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_collision), but you can also say [a car crash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_collision), [a traffic collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_collision) or even [a motor vehicle collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_collision). They all mean the same thing. The former two are more colloquial whereas the latter two would most likely be used by traffic cops in their official documents.